# getting date fields from oracle in correct format using Python and cx-oracle

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I am retrieving a load of data from one oracle database and then inserting it into another non linked database that is structurally the same.

I am doing it by doing:

```
select * from xxx where id = parameter
```

and

```
Select COLUMN_NAME from user_tab_columns where table_name=xxx
```

then with zip putting them in a dictionary as table_name:Data to build the insert from

Problem is it is returning the date fields as datetime.datetime(99, 12, 31, 0, 0). I need this as 31-dec-2999. How can I get it to return it like this or do I need to create a regex to do this?

I'm new to all this so if my method seems ridiculous feel free to say so and suggest a better method

Many thanks
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cx_Oracle` database adapter is giving you [`datetime.datetime()` *objects*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime). Use methods on those objects to format them to a string if you require a different output.

The [`datetime.strftime()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) would be best suited for your purposes:

```
dtobject.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
```

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> dtobject = datetime.datetime(2999, 12, 31, 0, 0)
>>> dtobject.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
'31-Dec-2999'
```

If, however, Oracle is really returning objects with the year set to `99` (not `2999`) you need to repair the data:

```
if dtobject.year < 100:
    dtobject = dtobject.replace(year=dtobject.year + 2900)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strftime`.

For example:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> print datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
2013-08-13 13:10
```

In your case, this can make it:

```
strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
```

where:

```
%b     locale's abbreviated month name (e.g., Jan)
%d     day of month (e.g., 01)
%Y     year
```