# getting proper date format from SQL search results (datetime.datetime)

Tags: python, oracle, python-3.x, cx-oracle

This is my first time using cx_oracle. Part of my project is to create a search engine that processes "SELECT FROM.." queries and displays them. This is for searching patient information and the tests he/she have been prescribed. I thought it would also be a good idea to return prescribe dates for tests.

Here is what I execute:

```
searchPatientName = "SELECT b.PATIENT_NO, a.NAME, c.TEST_NAME, b.TEST_DATE, b.RESULT FROM patient a, test_record b, test_type c WHERE b.TYPE_ID = c.TYPE_ID AND b.PATIENT_NO = a.HEALTH_CARE_NO AND a.NAME = :patient_name"

patientName = "Vera Fuselier"
search.execute(searchPatientName, patient_name=patientName)

rows = search.fetchall()                    
for row in rows:
    print(row)
break
```

The output I am getting is what I want for the project, but the date is not what I am wanting.

```
 (100103, 'Vera Fuselier', 'Blood Test', datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 30, 0, 0), 'Normal')
 (100103, 'Vera Fuselier', 'MRI', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 30, 0, 0), 'Sclerosis')
```

Please notice how the date is not displaying the way I want to (with datetime.datetime), and I can't figure out a way to fix this.

I've been using this to no avail: [getting date fields from oracle in correct format using Python and cx-oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207415/getting-date-fields-from-oracle-in-correct-format-using-python-and-cx-oracle)

How can I get the date to display in a format like: '12-08-30' for example?

Comment: Please also know that this is my first time using python.

Comment: did it help? then pls confirm the answer

Answer (score 4):

datetime is the date object of python, with that you could get any format you want
in your case you can get your format with:

```
import datetime
row[3].strftime('%y-%m-%d')
```

Now for clarification of what is happening. With `strftime()` you can get a Date or Time String out of your Datetimeobject. with `'%y-%m-%d'` I formated it.

`row[3]` should be your dateobject element.

`%y` returns the Year with 2 digits like `14` for 2014. If you want the whole year you have to type `%Y`

`%m` returns the number of month and `%d` the number of day.

there are also options like weekday, the name of the month, etc.

you can read about that in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

So now your code should look like this:

```
import datetime

#your code to read the file

for row in rows:
    row[3] = row[3].strftime('%y-%m-%d')
    print(row)

#some other code
```

Comment: when I tried to use the above code it says - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime' Can you please help with this error message

Comment: strftime is a method of the datetime object. If you try to execute it on a string it will not work.